# In C programing how to get the commandline arguments passed to a program

Tags: linux

We can get the arguments passed to a process using command "cat /proc/pid/cmdline".
But how to get this progrmmatically.

Comment: You should read [Lesson 14](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html) and you should also try to find the solution by yourself first. Your post shows no effort whatsoever.

Comment: I want to access these parameters in a function other than main(). So not able to use argc/argv[] thing.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `/proc` file:

```
int fd = open("/proc/$pid/cmdline", O_RDONLY);
```

and `read` from it. (The arguments are delimited by `'\0'`.)

The point of exposing this info in the filesystem is so that you don't need special functions for obtaining it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works, but it gives all the parameters in a single string having spaces removed between these params. Example :  "./server 6668 192.168.1.18"  is getting as "./server6668192.168.1.18". So, not able to distinguish between two different words.

Comment: The arguments are delimited by `'\0'`. `'\0'` doesn't print but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are passed to main() as a character array.
Try this simple program:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])                                          
{                                                                                  
    int i;                                                                         



for(i=0;i<argc;i++)                                                            
{                                                                              
    printf("%s\n",argv[i]);                                                    
}                                                                              

return 0;    
}
```

Comment: ah sorry, misunderstood.